# ¿Cómo obtengo datos de un array, dentro de otro array?

Tags: php

QUIERO ACCEDER A **time, home_scorer, score, away_scorer** y NO LOGRO DAR :/
GRACIAS POR SU AYUDA!

```
[

    {

        "match_id":"119596",
        "country_id":"169",
        "country_name":"England",
        "league_id":"62",
        "league_name":"Premier League",
        "match_date":"2016-10-30",
        "match_status":"FT",
        "match_time":"18:00",
        "match_hometeam_name":"Southampton",
        "match_hometeam_score":"0",
        "match_awayteam_name":"Chelsea",
        "match_awayteam_score":"2",
        "match_live":"1",
        "goalscorer": [
            {
                "time":"6'",
                "home_scorer":"",
                "score":"0 - 1",
                "away_scorer":"E.  Eden Hazard"
            },
            {
                "time":"55'",
                "home_scorer":"",
                "score":"0 - 2",
                "away_scorer":"D.  Diego  Costa"
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

Comment: Eso tiene mas pinta de JSON que de Array

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Imagínate que tienes el array almacendo en una variable llamada `$array`, entonces deberías acceder a la primera posición del array donde se encuentra `goalscorer` de la siguiente manera:

```
$goalscorer = $array[0]["goalscorer"];
```

De esta manera obtenemos el array `goalscorer`.

Posteriormente podemos recorrer cada objeto del array con un bucle `foreach`:

```
foreach($goalscorer as $goal){
    echo $goal["time"];
    echo $goal["home_scorer"];
    echo $goal["score"];
    echo $goal["away_scorer"];
}
```

Recuerda siempre que los arrays vienen definidos en un JSON mediante corchetes `[]` y cada uno de los objetos definidos en un array mediante llaves `{}`.

Comment: Gracias, de verdad me sirvió demasiado!

Comment: Para convertir en array asociativo el json  se debe usar el parametro true 
    **$array = json_decode($json, true));**

Answer (score 3):

Por tratarse de un arreglo en formato JSON primeramente debes decodificarlo a un arreglo que PHP pueda utilizar de la siguiente forma:

```
$startArray = json_decode('[{
                        "match_id":"119596",
                        "country_id":"169",
                        "country_name":"England",
                        "league_id":"62",
                        "league_name":"Premier League",
                        "match_date":"2016-10-30",
                        "match_status":"FT",
                        "match_time":"18:00",
                        "match_hometeam_name":"Southampton",
                        "match_hometeam_score":"0",
                        "match_awayteam_name":"Chelsea",
                        "match_awayteam_score":"2",
                        "match_live":"1",
                        "goalscorer": [{
                            "time":"6\'",
                            "home_scorer":"",
                            "score":"0 - 1",
                            "away_scorer":"E.  Eden Hazard"
                        },{
                            "time":"55\'",
                            "home_scorer":"",
                            "score":"0 - 2",
                            "away_scorer":"D.  Diego  Costa"
                        }]
        }]');
$array = json_decode('$array');
```

Después de eso puedes acceder a sus elementos y atributos según lo ocupes:

```
$goalscorer = $array[0]->goalscorer;
//var_dump($goalscorer);
foreach($goalscorer as $goal){
    echo $goal->time."<br>";
    echo $goal->home_scorer."<br>";
    echo $goal->score."<br>";
    echo $goal->away_scorer."<br>";
}
```

El motivo por el cual uso `->` es porque al hacer la función `json_decode()` el arreglo se convierte en un objeto, por lo que para poder acceder a sus atributos debes usar dicha notación en vez de la tradicional con casillas `[]`.

**Nota:** El motivo por el que usé `\` en el atributo `time` fue porque de lo contrario PHP pensaría que ahí estoy cerrando la cadena de JSON y mandaría error a la hora de compilar.

Comment: Gracias, la verdad si me funciono, te lo agradezco!

Comment: @ricardo-sauceda los Agradecimientos se agradece, pero también ha de cerrar la pregunta y dar la respuesta como valida, eso si es de agradecer...